# Tooltip with scroll div in richfaces

Tags: html, css, richfaces, tooltip, panel

I have problem with display rich:toolTip in rich:panel tag. Rich panel tag have style with overflow-y: auto. I have fixed max-height. When i navigate at my toolTip, which is in rich:dataTable in rich:column with the data which loading by dataTable component, My toolTip not show out of panel, only in this panel and scroll show.

How can i show my toolTip outside ? I used richfaces 3.3.3.Final

Comment: My toolTip have this style : { background-color: #FAE6B0;
padding: 7px;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #E5973E;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
float: left;
position: absolute;
display: none; }

Comment: This problem is only at ie, at other browser look good. For rich:panel i have this style: { border: 0px; 
  width:871px; 
   overflow-y: auto;
  max-height:500px;
  position: relative\9; /* IE 8 and below */ */ */
  /* IE Hack */
     height: expression(this.scrollHeight > 500 ? "500px" : "auto"); */ }